# Overloading subgraph so that derived graph objects can have subgraphs be made (networkx)

Tags: python, networkx

I am creating a derived DiGraph class some additional class variables. This means, when I try to call `G.subgraph()` that I get the error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I see from other posts that I want to overload the `subgraph` method so that I can pass the variables I need to `__init__` of my derived class, but I am having trouble figuring out exactly how to do so.

```
class DeBruijnGraph(nx.DiGraph):
    def __init__(self, kmer_size):
        nx.DiGraph.__init__(self)
        self.kmer_size = kmer_size
        self.sources = []
    #other added methods
    def subgraph(self, nbunch, copy=True):
        H = nx.DiGraph.subgraph(self, nbunch, copy)
        #how do I make H into a DeBruijnGraph()?
        #or use kwargs or something to pass self.kmer_size to init()?
```

The problematic line is `H = self.__class__()` in `digraph.py`. I really need to be able to have that either take in some `kwargs` or something. I could just copy the entire method into my derived class and modify that line.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying the entire method you could also make kmer_size a keyword:

```
import networkx as nx
class DeBruijnGraph(nx.DiGraph):
    def __init__(self, kmer_size=None):
        nx.DiGraph.__init__(self)
        self.kmer_size = kmer_size
        self.sources = []
    #other added methods
    def subgraph(self, nbunch, copy=True):
        H = nx.DiGraph.subgraph(self, nbunch)
        # adjust H.kmer_size etc here
        if copy:
            return DeBruijnGraph(H)
        else:
            return H

if __name__ == '__main__':
    G = DeBruijnGraph(2)
    G.add_edge(1,2)
    S = G.subgraph([1])
```